# "Can't bind to ngModel" when using component from another module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have hit a wall with this issue and I hope that somebody here can help me.

My **create-recipe.component** in my **recipe.module** needs to use the **raw-material-multi-select.component** from **shared-components.module**. I declare and export RawMaterialMultiSelect component in SharedComponents module and import it in Recipe module, but I get the following error: *Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-multiSelect'*. p-multiSelect is a PrimeNG component. I use the multiselect component in several other places and the solution works if the components are in the same module. But when I split them up I get this error. I am at a loss and hope someone can help me.

Here are my files:

**raw-material-multi-select.component.html**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="rawMaterialStore.rawMaterialIdentities$ | async" [(ngModel)]="selectedRawMaterials" placeholder="Ingredienser" class="filter"></p-multiSelect>
```

**raw-material-multi-select.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RawMaterialStoreService } from '../../raw-material/raw-material-store.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'raw-material-multi-select',
  templateUrl: './raw-material-multi-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./raw-material-multi-select.component.scss']
})
export class RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  
  selectedRawMaterials: string = "";

  constructor(public rawMaterialStore: RawMaterialStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**shared-components.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
import { RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent } from './raw-material-multi-select/raw-material-multi-select.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MultiSelectModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```

**create-recipe.component.html**

```
...
  <raw-material-multi-select></raw-material-multi-select>
...
```

And for good measure here is my **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    RecipesModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
...
```

Comment: You have to import FormsModule into your module.

Comment: @FatihErsoy you are absolutely correct! I imported FormsModule into shared-components.module.ts and now it works :D

Can you please post an answer, so I accept it? :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the `MultiSelectModule` & `FromsModule` might not be properly imported into `recipe.module`. You can add it into the `exports` array of `SharedComponentsModule` or directly import it in imports array of `recipe.module` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
import { RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent } from './raw-material-multi-select/raw-material-multi-select.component';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    FromsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RawMaterialMultiSelectComponent,
    MultiSelectModule,
    FromsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```